# remove parent if child node has no value

Tags: c#, xml

I want to remove parent elements from an XML structure if child is empty. 
My XML:

```
<Customers>
<customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Status>single</Status>
</Customer>
<customer>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Age></Age>
    <Status></Status>
</Customer>
</Customers>
```

Should become:

```
<Customers>
    <customer>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Age>25</Age>
        <Status>single</Status>
    </Customer>
    </Customers>
```

my code :

```
XmlElement element3 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("Age");
        element3.InnerText = str3;
        element1.AppendChild((XmlNode)element3);    
XmlElement element4 = xmlDocument.CreateElement("Status");
        element4.InnerText = str4;
        element1.AppendChild((XmlNode)element4);
```

How can I remove the parent "customer", if age and status child are empty?

Comment: Much easier with XDocument. And your code only Adds elements, I thought you wanted to remove something?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can use XPath syntax along with `SelectNodes()` method to get specific nodes from `XmlDocument` easily.</s>

Example to select `<Customer>` elements having child node `<Age>` and `<Status>` empty, then remove those selected elements :

```
var nodes = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Customer[Age = '' and Status = '']");
foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

**UPDATE :**

It seems that you're the one that construct the XML. So i'd suggest to check if `str3` and `str4` are empty, and if they are remove corresponding `<Customer>` element :

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str3) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(str4))
{
    element1.ParentNode.RemoveChild(element1);
}
```

Comment: which line i should past the code above in my xml ?

Comment: how if str is more then 2 ?
Can i do in this way ?

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str3) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(str4) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(str5))
{
    element1.ParentNode.RemoveChild(element1);
}

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're creating a new file and adding each element after the validation. I think this should work for you:

```
XDocument input = XDocument.Load("customers.xml");
XDocument output = new XDocument();
output.Add(new XElement("Customers"));
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = input.Element("Customers").Elements("customer");
foreach (XElement el in elements)
{
    string age = el.Element("Age").Value;
    string status = el.Element("Status").Value;
    if (age != "" || status != "")
    {
        output.Element("Customers").Add(el);
    }
}
output.Save("customers.xml");
```